# Why can't my Java/SalesForce app create JAXBContext due to a security restriction?

Tags: java, web-services, soap, jaxb, salesforce

I was on one [Java/Salesforce tutorial](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/sforce70/sforce_API_quickstart_samplecode.html#wp1197527) but I couldn't get it to work as is because SoapBindingStub seems to be obsolete code based upon depreciated libraries.  So I tried to mesh the code with code from [JAX-WS Quick Start](http://wiki.developerforce.com/index.php/JAX-WS_Quick_Start), but this didn't quite work either.  No matter what I did, ultimately the sample console application would suffer exceptions, complaining "**Web Service Exception creating salesface port.: Unable to create JAXBContext due to the security restriction on class javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException**".

I gave up (for the moment) trying to mash the two codes, and instead am now just working on abstracting the JAX-WS Quickstart.java so I can understand wow it works and reuse its methods in other applications.

No matter how I slice and dice the code, it always gets stuck at the same location with essentially that same error.

Here is the current code for method which is persistantly failing:

```
private void initPort() 
{
    try 
    {
        URL wsdlLocation = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("META-INF/enterprise.wsdl");
        if (wsdlLocation == null) 
        {
            WebServiceException webServiceException = new WebServiceException("enterprise.wsdl not found!");
            ExceptionToolkit.display("Web Service Exception can't find enterprise.wsdl", webServiceException);
            throw webServiceException;
        }
        else {System.out.println("\nFOUND enterprise.wsdl!!!\n\n");}

        QName qName = new QName("urn:enterprise.soap.sforce.com", "SforceService");
        SforceService sforceService = new SforceService( wsdlLocation, qName );
        System.out.println("\nsforceService INITIALIZED. About to get Soap.\n\n");
        Soap soap = (sforceService).getSoap();
        System.out.println("\nWe have soap.\n\n");
        setPort (soap);
    } 
    catch (WebServiceException webServiceException) 
    { 
        ExceptionToolkit.display("Web Service Exception creating salesface port", webServiceException); 
        return;
    }
}
```

Here is the error, including output immediately before and after:

```
Running main loop



FOUND enterprise.wsdl!!!



sforceService INITIALIZED. About to get Soap.




Web Service Exception creating salesface port: Unable to create JAXBContext due to the security restriction
on class javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException
javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Unable to create JAXBContext due to the security restriction
    at com.sun.xml.ws.model.AbstractSEIModelImpl.createJAXBContext(AbstractSEIModelImpl.java:131)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.model.AbstractSEIModelImpl.postProcess(AbstractSEIModelImpl.java:63)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.model.RuntimeModeler.buildRuntimeModel(RuntimeModeler.java:224)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.addSEI(WSServiceDelegate.java:588)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(WSServiceDelegate.java:291)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(WSServiceDelegate.java:274)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(WSServiceDelegate.java:267)
    at javax.xml.ws.Service.getPort(Unknown Source)
    at com.sforce.soap.enterprise.SforceService.getSoap(SforceService.java:53)
    at hu.flux.salesforce.LoginToolkit.initPort(LoginToolkit.java:78)
    at hu.flux.salesforce.LoginToolkit.doLogin(LoginToolkit.java:122)
    at hu.flux.salesforce.LoginToolkit.<init>(LoginToolkit.java:49)
    at hu.flux.salesforce.samples.Quickstart.mainLoop(Quickstart.java:55)
    at hu.flux.salesforce.samples.Quickstart.<init>(Quickstart.java:28)
    at hu.flux.salesforce.samples.Quickstart.main(Quickstart.java:21)
Caused by: java.security.PrivilegedActionException: com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 2 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
java.lang.StackTraceElement does not have a no-arg default constructor.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at java.lang.StackTraceElement
        at public java.lang.StackTraceElement[] java.lang.Throwable.getStackTrace()
        at java.lang.Throwable
        at java.lang.Exception
        at com.sforce.ws.ConnectionException
        at com.sforce.ws.SoapFaultException
        at com.sforce.soap.enterprise.fault.ApiFault
        at public javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement com.sforce.soap.enterprise.fault.ObjectFactory.createFault(com.sforce.soap.enterprise.fault.ApiFault)
        at com.sforce.soap.enterprise.fault.ObjectFactory
com.sforce.ws.types.Time does not have a no-arg default constructor.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at com.sforce.ws.types.Time
        at public com.sforce.ws.types.Time com.sforce.soap.enterprise.sobject.BusinessHours.getFridayEndTime()
        at com.sforce.soap.enterprise.sobject.BusinessHours
        at public com.sforce.soap.enterprise.sobject.BusinessHours com.sforce.soap.enterprise.sobject.ObjectFactory.createBusinessHours()
        at com.sforce.soap.enterprise.sobject.ObjectFactory

    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.model.AbstractSEIModelImpl.createJAXBContext(AbstractSEIModelImpl.java:124)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 2 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
java.lang.StackTraceElement does not have a no-arg default constructor.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at java.lang.StackTraceElement
        at public java.lang.StackTraceElement[] java.lang.Throwable.getStackTrace()
        at java.lang.Throwable
        at java.lang.Exception
        at com.sforce.ws.ConnectionException
        at com.sforce.ws.SoapFaultException
        at com.sforce.soap.enterprise.fault.ApiFault
        at public javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement com.sforce.soap.enterprise.fault.ObjectFactory.createFault(com.sforce.soap.enterprise.fault.ApiFault)
        at com.sforce.soap.enterprise.fault.ObjectFactory
com.sforce.ws.types.Time does not have a no-arg default constructor.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at com.sforce.ws.types.Time
        at public com.sforce.ws.types.Time com.sforce.soap.enterprise.sobject.BusinessHours.getFridayEndTime()
        at com.sforce.soap.enterprise.sobject.BusinessHours
        at public com.sforce.soap.enterprise.sobject.BusinessHours com.sforce.soap.enterprise.sobject.ObjectFactory.createBusinessHours()
        at com.sforce.soap.enterprise.sobject.ObjectFactory

    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException$Builder.check(IllegalAnnotationsException.java:66)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getTypeInfoSet(JAXBContextImpl.java:422)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:270)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:103)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.api.JAXBRIContext.newInstance(JAXBRIContext.java:89)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.model.AbstractSEIModelImpl$1.run(AbstractSEIModelImpl.java:126)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.model.AbstractSEIModelImpl$1.run(AbstractSEIModelImpl.java:125)
    ... 16 more



1. Login
2. Get Accounts
3. Update Accounts
4. Get Server Timestamp
5. Exit
Enter a menu option:
```

The last line (chronologically) on the stack which refers to my own code is:

```
at hu.flux.salesforce.LoginToolkit.initPort(LoginToolkit.java:78)
```

System.out.println statements in the source confirms that this is what the execution terminates.  This line specifically states:

```
Soap soap = (sforceService).getSoap();
```

Does anyone know how or why this could transcend a security restriction ultimately leaving java unable to create the JAXBContext?

Comment: Downvoting a legitimate problem... very helpful.  :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally have login working... for both the first tutorial I went to work on and in the spliced up code derived from JAX WS Quickstart.  If it helps anyone, here is my complete LoginToolkit class.  (Sorry, I'm a bit lazy about commenting when I'm not getting paid for my time or output.)

```
/**
 * 
 */
package hu.flux.salesforce;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
import javax.xml.ws.BindingProvider;
import javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException;
import javax.xml.ws.handler.MessageContext;

import hu.flux.exceptions.ExceptionToolkit;
import hu.flux.input.PromptUser;

import com.sforce.soap.enterprise.InvalidIdFault;
import com.sforce.soap.enterprise.LoginResult;
import com.sforce.soap.enterprise.SessionHeader;
import com.sforce.soap.enterprise.SforceService;
import com.sforce.soap.enterprise.Soap;
import com.sun.xml.bind.api.JAXBRIContext;
import com.sun.xml.ws.api.message.Headers;
import com.sun.xml.ws.developer.WSBindingProvider;

/**
 * @author Brian Kessler
 *
 */
public class LoginToolkit {

    private Soap binding = null;
    private LoginResult loginResult = null;;

    public void setBinding(Soap binding) { this.binding = binding; }
    public Soap getBinding() { return binding; }

    public void setLoginResult(LoginResult loginResult) { this.loginResult = loginResult; }
    public LoginResult getLoginResult() { return loginResult; }

    /**
     * 
     */
    public LoginToolkit() { doLogin(); }

    private boolean doLogin()
    {   
        //String userName = getUserInput("Enter user name: ").trim();
        //String password = getUserInput("Enter password: ").trim();
        String userName = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
        String password = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
        binding = bindEnterpriseWSDL();

        System.out.println("LOGGING IN NOW....");
        try { loginResult = binding.login ( userName, password ); }
        catch (InvalidIdFault invalidIdFault) { return loginExceptionCaught("invalid id fault", invalidIdFault); }
        catch (com.sforce.soap.enterprise.LoginFault loginFault) { return loginExceptionCaught("login fault", loginFault); }
        catch (com.sforce.soap.enterprise.UnexpectedErrorFault unexpectedErrorFault) { return loginExceptionCaught("unexpected error fault", unexpectedErrorFault); }

        // Check if the password has expired
        return (loginResult.isPasswordExpired()) ? passwordExpired() : bindSession();
    }

    private Soap bindEnterpriseWSDL()
    {
        try 
        {
            URL wsdlLocation = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("META-INF/enterprise.wsdl");
            if (wsdlLocation == null) 
            {
                WebServiceException webServiceException = new WebServiceException("enterprise.wsdl not found!");
                ExceptionToolkit.display ("Web Service Exception could not find enterprise.wsdl.", webServiceException);
                throw new WebServiceException(webServiceException);
            }
            else { System.out.println ("\n\n\nenterprise.wsdl WAS found!\n\n\n");}

            QName qName = new QName("urn:enterprise.soap.sforce.com", "SforceService");
            SforceService sforceService = new SforceService(wsdlLocation, qName);
            Soap soap = sforceService.getSoap();
            return soap; 
        } 
        catch (WebServiceException webServiceException) 
        {
            ExceptionToolkit.display ("Web Service Exception creating salesface port.", webServiceException);
            throw new WebServiceException(webServiceException);
        }
    }


    private WSBindingProvider enableGzip(BindingProvider bindingProvider) 
    {
        //Enable GZip compression
        Map<String, List<String>> httpHeaders = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
        httpHeaders.put("Content-Encoding", Collections.singletonList("gzip"));
        httpHeaders.put("Accept-Encoding", Collections.singletonList("gzip"));
        Map<String, Object> reqContext = bindingProvider.getRequestContext();
        reqContext.put(MessageContext.HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS, httpHeaders);
        return (WSBindingProvider) bindingProvider;
    }

    private boolean passwordExpired() 
    {
        System.out.println("An error has occured.  Your password has expired.");
        return false;
    }   

    private boolean bindSession() 
    {
        //binding._setProperty(Soap BindingStub.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, loginResult.getServerUrl());
        WSBindingProvider bindingProvider = ((WSBindingProvider) binding);
        bindingProvider.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, loginResult.getServerUrl());
        bindingProvider = enableGzip (bindingProvider);

        // Create a new session header object and add the session id from the login return object
        SessionHeader sessionHeader = new SessionHeader();
        sessionHeader.setSessionId(loginResult.getSessionId());
        bindingProvider = setJAXBContext (bindingProvider, sessionHeader);


        reportLoginSuccess();

        return true; // return true to indicate that we are logged in,  pointed at the right url and have our security token in place.
    }   

    private WSBindingProvider setJAXBContext (WSBindingProvider bindingProvider, SessionHeader sessionHeader) 
    {
        JAXBContext jc;
        try { jc = JAXBContext.newInstance("com.sforce.soap.enterprise"); } 
        catch (JAXBException jaxbException) 
        {
            ExceptionToolkit.display ("Error creating JAXBContext instance.", jaxbException);
            throw new WebServiceException(jaxbException);
        }

        bindingProvider.setOutboundHeaders(Headers.create((JAXBRIContext) jc, sessionHeader));
        return bindingProvider;
    }

    private void reportLoginSuccess() 
    {
        System.out.println("Login was successfull.");
        System.out.print("The returned session id is: ");
        System.out.println(getLoginResult().getSessionId());
        System.out.print("Your logged in user id is: ");
        System.out.println(getLoginResult().getUserId() + " \n\n");
    }

    private boolean loginExceptionCaught(String label, Exception exception) 
    { 
        ExceptionToolkit.display ("A " + label + " has occured.", exception);
        return false;
    } 

    public boolean checkLogin() 
    {
        // check to see if we are already logged in
        if (this.getLoginResult() == null) 
        {
            System.out.println("Run the login sample before the others.\n");
            PromptUser.getUserInput("Hit enter to continue: ");
            System.out.println("\n");
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to make a web service that has a subclass of `java.lang.Exception` or `StackTraceElement` in its contract. You can't do that. The only way to handle exceptions is to use faults.

Have you made all this work outside salesforce?

Note that your code goes to trouble to manually initialize a JAXB context, but you're not communicating that into the JAX-WS calls, so that stack is making a new JAXB context and getting into trouble trying. Did you remember to pass it into the binding provider, as in ...

```
 try {
        jc = JAXBContext.newInstance("com.salesforce.sei");
        bindingProvider.setOutboundHeaders(Headers.create((JAXBRIContext) jc, sh));
    } catch (JAXBException e) {
        System.out.println("Error creating JAXBContext instance " + e.getMessage());
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: I'm not using any subclasses in this code.  The tutorial I'm working on is all about using Java with SalesForce, so I'm not sure how I could take sensibly salesforce out of the equation.

Comment: BTW, I think the exceptions are handled fine, I'm just not clear why I'm getting this particular one when I do as there seems to be some sort of restriction on either accessing the WSDL or creating the SOAP object.

Comment: If you google for JAX-B and StackTraceElement, you'll see what I'm talking about. e.g. http://forums.java.net/node/670152

Comment: Cheers for the lead, but I'm not really seeing any parallel between what I'm doing and what they were discussing on the thread beyond some had the same error... and it seems that thread ultimately went unsolved anyway.  :-/  I'll put the rest of my class up top (since it won't fit in here) hoping that makes it clearer what I'm failing to do...

Comment: I'm quite sure that the immediate problem right now is the line "Soap soap = sforceService.getSoap();"

Comment: Hmm. Note that it's creating a new JAXB context, not using the one you created.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response... I didn't catch the edit until now.  You are correct that it's creating a new JAXB Context.  The code aborts from the stated exception before it ever gets to the point where I create it.... Maybe I can move that code up? Trying...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Jax-WS, see the [Jax-WS/salesforce quickstart](http://wiki.developerforce.com/index.php/JAX-WS_Quick_Start), there's a long list of [java samples for salesfoce on the wiki](http://wiki.developerforce.com/index.php/Web_Services_API#Java)

Comment: I've been looking at quickstart... I'm trying to figure out how to apply that code outside of the sample package... but obviously I've overlooked or misunderstood something

Comment: There's a separate quickstart for jax-ws, which i linked to.

Comment: That's exactly the quick start code that I am trying to use as a reference to make this other code work.  Thank you for pointing out its existence, but my problem is more specific.

Comment: Just tried dumping the entire Quickstart.java into my project, commenting out most everything but Quickstart.doLogin(), changing its signature to public boolean doLogin(), and calling it from my Samples class instead of Samples.doLogin() ... the Quickstart class dies with pretty much the same error at the equivalent point in the process.